# Type Date return content

Tags: return

Please see content below, confused on what to put for return that has type Date

```
@Override
public int maxCapacity() {
    return 3;
}
@Override
public String area() {
    return "10";
}
@Override
public Date whenBuilt() {
    return ***[What should I return here?]***
}
```

Comment: some Date instance?

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: `new Date()` gives you current date

Answer (score 0):

Date methods must to return Date instance or null..

You can just `return new Date();`, but it will always fresh date.

Method `whenBuilt` looks like some date in the past, so you should to make some date, in constructor for example.

```
class A {
  private final Date createdAt;
  A() {
    createdAt = new Date();
  }
  public Date whenBuilt() {
    return createdAt;
  }
}
```

`@Override` annotation points to your class is extension from some base class.
Try to check base class, may be built date is already in there.